# How to use Format from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, format, checkstyle

I use Eclipse and Sun-Checkstyle(I created a copy and changed some options) for my code. 
How can I adapt the Auto-Formatter from Eclipse to my actual checkstyle?

And another Question: If I enter Ctrl-Shift-F for Auto-Formatter. Only Line-Break will be executed. Problems like white sprace  will not be auto corrected.

Example:`a=1`

Fore and after "=" should be a white space. If i use Ctrl-Shift-F, code stays the same..
How can i solve that problem?

Comment: You really should only ask 1 question per post - it helps other users find relevant information in the future.

Comment: Open the Eclipse Preferences and look at Java > Code Style > Formatter

Comment: yea, i checked Formatter-Options in Code Style. White Space-Settings are all ok. But it wont auto format, wenn i press Ctrl-Shift-F. Only the line width will be changed.